# how to remove the double quotes in a csv

Tags: linux, awk, sed, csv

I have a CSV file like

```
a.csv
"1,2,3,4,9"
"1,2,3,6,24"
"1,2,6,8,28"
"1,2,4,6,30"
```

I want something like

```
b.csv
1,2,3,4,9
1,2,3,6,24
1,2,6,8,28
1,2,4,6,30
```

I tried `awk '{split($0,a,"\"");` But did not help.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You mean you want to delete the double quote ?  This `"` ?

Comment: Yes exactly I want to remove the " "

Comment: may I ask what country you're from, because I've lived in the US for 10 years, and never heard anyone refer to double quotes as inverted comma

Comment: In British English, quotation marks are called inverted commas.But anyway no worries

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `gsub()` function for global substitution

```
$ awk '{gsub(/"/,"")};1' input.csv                    
1,2,3,4,9
1,2,3,6,24
1,2,6,8,28
1,2,4,6,30
```

To send output to new file use `>` shell operator:

```
awk '{gsub(/"/,"")};1' input.csv > output.csv
```

Your splitting to array approach also can be used, although it's not necessary, but you can use it as so:

```
$ awk '{split($0,a,/"/); print a[2]}' input.csv       
1,2,3,4,9
1,2,3,6,24
1,2,6,8,28
1,2,4,6,30
```

Note that in this particular question the general pattern is that quotes are in the beginning and end of the line, which means we  can also treat that as field separator, where field 1 is null, field 2 is `1,2,3,4`, and field 3 is also null. Thus, we can do:

```
awk -F '"' '{print $2}' input.csv
```

And we can also take out substring of the whole line:

```
awk '{print substr($0,2,length()-2)}' quoted.csv
```

Speaking of stripping first and last characters, there's  a [whole post on stackoverflow about that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12362142/3701431) with other tools such as `sed` and POSIX shell.

Answer (score 10):

Simplest approach:

```
tr -d '"' <a.csv >b.csv
```

Comment: This is the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution with `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/"//g' a.csv > b.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this command

```
awk '{gsub("\"",RS);print}' a.csv >  b.csv
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work.